# Cheapest way to make a single object Enumerable?

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

I have an interface function that returns an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` collection.

Some of my classes only use one hardcoded instance of `MyObject`, but still need to implement the interface.

Currently I am just creating a System.Array like so:

```
public class SomeClass : IMyInterface
{
    private MyObject _myObject;

    public IEnumerable<MyObject> IMyInterface.GetMyObjects()
    {
        return new MyObject[] { _myObject };
    }
}
```

I just wondered if there was a more efficient way, or any magic to cast the object itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just...

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> IMyInterface.GetMyObjects()
{
    yield return _myObject;
}
```

...but consider that this will cause the compiler to generate a whole state machine class for it to work. If that sounds cheap for you, OK. Otherwise, the array solution looks fine. You may want to pre-create the array if there's no problem in reusing its instance.

Comment: <facepalm>. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should be considerably cheap:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> IMyInterface.GetMyObjects()
    {
        return new MyObject[1] { _myObject };
    }
```

Comment: This is no different from what the OP currently has.